# How do I get all values to echo with mysqli_fetch_assoc?

Tags: php, unity-game-engine

I'm pretty new to php, so don't really know how to do much, but from what I've looked up, this should echo all values from the two fields.

```php
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'unityaccess');

    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "1: Connection failed"; //error code 1 = connection failed
        exit();
    }

    $username = $_POST["name"];

    $idcheckquery = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username . "';";
    $idcheck = mysqli_query($con, $idcheckquery) or die("7: ID check query failed"); //error code 8 = couldn't get user's id

    $existingid = mysqli_fetch_assoc($idcheck);
    $userid = $existingid["id"];

    $itemfindquery = "SELECT itemid, equipped FROM inventory WHERE userid = '" . $userid ."';";
    $itemfind = mysqli_query($con, $itemfindquery) or die("9: Couldn't find items");

    while($row = $mysqli_fetch_assoc($itemfind)){
        echo $row["itemid"] . ", " . $row["equipped"] . " ";
    }
?>
```

I expect this to, when it is called in unity, to print a list of all the values in each list, but instead it doesn't echo anything.

Comment: Remove the `$` from the `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` function and it should work. But there are some security and efficiency issues with your code.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. But I don't really know how to code efficiently or securely, so some pointers could be nice.

Comment: Basically, read more about the object oriented paradigm (which will help a lot in the long run, but maybe that can wait) and, more importantly, read about prepared statements to avoid SQL injections (and code more easily). Although it's even easier to use prepared statements with the object oriented paradigm.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` function is being used as a variable (`$`). Just remove the dollar sign and it will work.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($itemfind)){
    echo $row["itemid"] . ", " . $row["equipped"] . " ";
}
```

Also, try to use prepared statements to fight against SQL injections.